# Is 'More stricter' gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar

The news company I work for just read out a script saying, *"More stricter measures have been imposed across Asia..'*

Surely it should just be, *"Stricter measures have been imposed across Asia..'*

Am I right in saying this isn't grammatically correct? If so, is there a name to describe it?

Comment: “More” in the sense of quantity. *A larger number of stricter measures have been...*

Comment: Hachi, isn't that already implied? Stricter is a quantifier too.

Comment: Jim, typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: Initially they imposed, say, 10 stricter measures, now the need more, say, 15 stricter measures.

Comment: More stricter is an error. Even more strict would make the point. It has to do with comparatives.

Comment: @Xanne - more refers to “stricter measures” not to “stricter”, “more stricter measures” is grammatically correct.

Comment: To me, 'stricter measures' already implies additional measures to the current measures.

Comment: A “stricter measure”  is a countable entity. You can have 1, 5,  or 10 for instance. . But you may need more, as in your example sentence.

Comment: You can say that by using 'stricter measures'. Why do you need an extra quantifier?

Comment: The above comments are correct, but it needs to be pointed out that expressions like "more stricter" are often used to mean "even stricter than more strict" in informal contexts.  This is usually done with a slight humorous intent.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more context if the example sentence is grammatical or not. In the right context, it could be: "(*Strict* measures) have been imposed across the UK. (*Stricter* measures) were imposed across Asia last week. Today, even more (*stricter* measures) were applied across Asia." That series of sentences is grammatical—even though the last sentence is stylistically dubious. In short, it depends on how the word is being used. Is it acting as an adjective or part of a compound noun? Regardless, most people would not use it in that way,

Comment: I read it as applying both *more* and *stricter*, independently of each other, to the noun.  More measures have been imposed, and they are stricter.

Comment: It should be 'more strict' or 'stricter'.   'More stricter' doesn't stand the test of grammar.

Comment: Cuckoo, @Hachi's point is that "stricter measures" refers to an unspecified number of measures characterized by greater strictness. "More stricter measures" denotes a larger number of such measures. The answer to your question "Why do you need an extra quantifier?" is "you probably don't, but in some contexts, you might."  In the full context of the script you're asking about, there could be something justifying the phrase.  However, in such contexts it would probably be better to say "additional stricter measures" to avoid the awkwardness and potential ambiguity of "more stricter measures."